# Macro Excel : just execute active rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have some case on my rows just have 70000 and can increment anytime can you guys help, to find what code to take just active cell?

```
Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DateFrom"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-4],""HH"")"
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G99999")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code like below. Note column A reference which you need to adjust to work out the last row. It should be changed to suit.

```
Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "DateFrom"
Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-4],""HH"")"
Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row )
```

Comment: Hi Shirvallabha Redij , Thankyou for your help..
It's Work.